# replace groups based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having a data.frame (`df`), see example, that contains information about people. Based on a key column (`sleutel`), I know if people live together (e.g. form a family) or not. Now, I need to create new columns with information about the 'head' of the family.

```
     name   sex gzverh   sleutel gzhfd lft
1 Loekens   Man      6  1847LS 9     3  49
2   Kemel Vrouw      5 1847LK 10     2  18
3   Kemel   Man      5 1847LK 10     2  22
4 Boersma Vrouw      4 1847LK 10     2  52
5   Kemel   Man      2 1847LK 10     1  54
```

So for example: row 5, Kemel, Male and gzhfd 1 (= head of the family Kemel). He is married to mrs. Boersma (same key). I want to mutate a new column (`lfthb`) with the age of the head of the family for all family members. So should become something like:

```
     name  sex  gzverh   sleutel gzhfd lft lfthb
1 Loekens   Man      6  1847LS 9     3  49    NA
2   Kemel Vrouw      5 1847LK 10     2  18    54
3   Kemel   Man      5 1847LK 10     2  22    54
4 Boersma Vrouw      4 1847LK 10     2  52    54
5   Kemel   Man      2 1847LK 10     1  54    54
```

I tried multiple ways with `dplyr` using multiple combinations of `group_by`,  `case_when` and `if_else` statements. And I manage to mutate the column for the head of the family itself. But not for the other members.

For example, evidently only changes the value for the head itself:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(lfthb  = case_when(sleutel == lag(sleutel) & gzhfd == 1 ~ lft))
```

But how to include the `gzhfd == 1` after the `~`?

dput of example data:

```
structure(list(naam = c("Loekens", "Kemel", "Kemel", "Boersma", 
"Kemel"), gesl = c("Man", "Vrouw", "Man", "Vrouw", "Man"), gzverh = c(6L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 2L), sleutel = c("1847LS 9", "1847LK 10", "1847LK 10", 
"1847LK 10", "1847LK 10"), gzhfd = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 1), lft = c(49, 
18, 22, 52, 54)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `replace` and `ifelse` will do the job, i.e.,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(sleutel) %>% 
 mutate(lfthb = ifelse(any(gzhfd == 1), replace(lft, gzhfd != 1, lft[gzhfd == 1]), NA))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 7
> # Groups:   sleutel [2]
>   naam    gesl  gzverh sleutel   gzhfd   lft lfthb
>   <chr>   <chr>  <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 Loekens Man        6 1847LS 9      3    49    NA
> 2 Kemel   Vrouw      5 1847LK 10     2    18    54
> 3 Kemel   Man        5 1847LK 10     2    22    54
> 4 Boersma Vrouw      4 1847LK 10     2    52    54
> 5 Kemel   Man        2 1847LK 10     1    54    54
> ```

As @Ronak mentions, we can omit the `replace` part

```
df %>% 
 group_by(sleutel) %>% 
 mutate(lfthb = if (any(gzhfd == 1)) lft[gzhfd == 1] else NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

A data.table approach (returns -INF instead of NA for the group with missing data):

```
dt<-df %>% as.data.table() %>% 
  .[gzhfd==1, lfthb := lft, by="sleutel"] %>% 
  .[,lfthb:= max(lfthb,na.rm = T), by="sleutel"]
```